# PHP Using an array within a mysql query with PDO binds

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've had a look at other stack overflow answers but I didn't see anything similar to my problem other than the error code.

I'm trying to use an array in my query which works but I'm not sure why with the :`start` and :`offset` binds it fails to run.

```
$location = array("England", "America", "Australia"); 

$qMarks = str_repeat('?,', count($location) - 1) . '?';

//Query
$sql=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM adverts WHERE location IN ($qMarks) AND status = 2 LIMIT :limit OFFSET :start");
$sql->bindValue(':limit', (int) $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindValue(':start', (int) $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->execute($location);
$adverts=$sql->fetchAll();
```

I'm not sure why with the limit and offset binds present it doesn't run, is it to do with that you can't combining positional placeholders.

Update 1 -

If I remove the array and the qMark and change the execute to `sql->execute();`

then the binds run

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix `?` bindings and `:param` bindings in one prepared statement.

So, you need something like this:

```
$location = array("England", "America", "Australia");

$qMarks = str_repeat('?,', count($location) - 1) . '?'; 

$location[] = (int)$limit;
$location[] = (int)$offset;
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM adverts WHERE location IN ($qMarks) AND status = 2 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?");
$sql->execute($location);
```

Comment: Isn't the '?' only supported by mysqli because you need to use bind_param("ss", value, value"); and bind_param is undefined in pdo?

Comment: Nope, you can use both in `PDO`, but not in the same prepared statement.

Comment: Something along these lines?

("SELECT * FROM adverts WHERE location IN ($qMarks) AND status = 2 LIMIT (limits) VALUES (?)");

Comment: Ah I see what direction to go in with the code above I get an "Syntax error or access violation" starting at "OFFSET".